# How do you code a box-shadow that creates this design?

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

I designed this tile with a box-shadow using Figma. The box-shadow is positioned to the top of the tile and centered, 40px in from the left and right side, and 16px in from the bottom. The blur is 48px with an y-offset of 24px. The color is (0,0,0,0.16).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't provided the dimensions of your tile, I made a tile that follows the box shadow properties that you want (with made-up dimensions):

```css
body {
  background:#F1F2F4;
}

#tile {
  margin-top:40px;
  margin-left:40px;
  width:300px;
  height:120px;
  background:#ffffff;
  border-radius:3px;
  box-shadow:0px 24px 48px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16);
}
```

```html
<div id="tile"></div>
```

For more information on the `box-shadow` property:

- https://alligator.io/css/box-shadow/
- https://teamtreehouse.com/community/what-is-the-difference-between-spread-and-blur-radius-properties

Comment: That's the property of the box-shadow, but as you see I have a tile on top that has no shadow. With your help, I figured it out using positioning and z-index.

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
    background:#F1F2F4;
}

#tile {
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    left: 30px;
    width: 380px;
    height: 136px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

#shadow {
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 300px;
    height: 120px;
    background: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 24px 48px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16);
}
```

```html
<div id="tile">
    <div id="shadow"></div>
</div>
```